# How much maximum time one has to spend in hell?

Tags: naraka, hell

How much maximum time one has to spend in hell ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/permanent-hell-in-hinduism

Comment: the Brahma Sutras say that only God knows the karma that is meted out to anyone. Only God knows.